# Why does HasCallStack still add stack frames when using withFrozenCallStack?

Tags: haskell, callstack

GHC 8 provides `HasCallStack` from the `GHC.Stack` module, which allows functions to request a stack frame be recorded when they are called. It also provides the `withFrozenCallStack` function, which “freezes” the call stack so that no further frames can be added to it.

In simple scenarios, this works as I would expect. For example:

```
ghci> let foo :: HasCallStack => CallStack
          foo = callStack
ghci> foo
[("foo",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = "interactive", srcLocModule = "Ghci2", srcLocFile = "<interactive>", srcLocStartLine = 8, srcLocStartCol = 1, srcLocEndLine = 8, srcLocEndCol = 4})]
ghci> withFrozenCallStack foo
[]
```

When I call `foo` normally, I get a stack frame, but when I wrap it with `withFrozenCallStack`, I don’t. Perfect. However, when the example gets only slightly more complicated, it stops behaving like I expect:

```
ghci> let foo :: CallStack
          foo = bar
          bar :: HasCallStack => CallStack
          bar = callStack
ghci> foo
[("bar",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = "interactive", srcLocModule = "Ghci9", srcLocFile = "<interactive>", srcLocStartLine = 24, srcLocStartCol = 11, srcLocEndLine = 24, srcLocEndCol = 14})]
ghci> withFrozenCallStack foo
[("bar",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = "interactive", srcLocModule = "Ghci9", srcLocFile = "<interactive>", srcLocStartLine = 24, srcLocStartCol = 11, srcLocEndLine = 24, srcLocEndCol = 14})]
```

By adding this simple layer of indirection, the stack frame still gets included, despite my use of `withFrozenCallStack`. Why?

Conceptually, my understanding of `HasCallStack` is that it is like an implicit use of `pushCallStack` on the current call stack, and `pushCallStack` has no effect on a frozen call stack. Why, then, does `withFrozenCallStack` not prevent the above stack frame from being added to the call stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `foo` is a static value of type `CallStack`. Note that it does *not* have an `HasCallStack` constraint.

It does not matter how and where you use `foo`, it will always refer to this particular `CallStack`. It does not matter that `foo` itself is defined using `bar` which uses the `HasCallStack` machinery – you could just statically define `foo = [("bar",…`.

Try adding `HasCallStack =>` to `foo`’s type signature. Does it now behave the way you expect?

Comment: Ahh, of course, that makes sense. My intuition about implicit parameters in Haskell is clearly not the best, since this would apply to any implicit parameter, not just `HasCallStack`. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. With a normal implicit parameter, you would get an error if it is not explicitly bound where you stop using the constraint. But with `HasCallStack` the compiler detects that and magically binds the initial call stack.

Comment: Aha, yes, that makes sense—you’re right again. :) The magical nature of `HasCallStack` is certainly a little confusing. I still don’t think I completely understand the intricacies of how `HasCallStack` constraints are inferred, but fortunately that doesn’t seem to be too much of an issue for me in practice, haha.

Comment: @AlexisKing The documentation [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Stack.html#t:CallStack) describes this particular magic.